# Can a Major Image illusion move outside of the range in which it was originally cast?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, illusion

Major Image (relevant sections):

> You create the image of an object, a creature, or some other visible
> phenomenon that is no larger than a 20.foot cube. The image appears at
> a spot that you can see within range and lasts for the duration.
>
> As long as you are within range of the illusion, you can use your action
> to cause the image to move to any other spot within range. As the
> image changes location, you can alter its appearance so that its
> movements appear natural for the image. For example, if you create an
> image of a creature and move it, you can alter the image so that it
> appears to be walking.
>
> **At Higher Levels:** When you cast this spell using a spell slot of 6th
> level or higher, the spell lasts until dispelled, without requiring
> your concentration.

I initially presumed this to mean you can create an illusion limited by the 20ft cube maximum size, and then the illusion can move within the original 120ft casting radius, with no option to leave it. But upon reading it again, it seems that if the caster is within range of the illusion, the character can command the illusion to move outside any initial range, and indeed can have the illusion follow the character around the map for miles. Is this correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, you can move the image out of the original range

"*Within range of the illusion*" refers to the 20 ft cube illusionary object or creature, NOT the 120 ft casting radius.

As long as you are within 120 ft radius of the illusionary object, you may move it to any other point within range. This lets illusionists keep one persistent Major Image for any amount of time if they can keep using actions to keep it near them.

What defines "*any other point within range*" however, is up to discussion. It could mean you may move the object either 120 ft within the caster, or 120 ft within the illusionary object.

Comment: It may be valuable to put that discussion mentioned in the last paragraph into the question, to more definitively answer the question. (It is a rather central point of the question to just give a shrug to.)

Comment: @SevenSidedDie put the discussion into the question? Or into my answer? I think you meant the latter, but it is unclear if you are addressing me or the Asker.

Comment: Sorry, yes, into the answer! Slip of the typing fingers.

Answer (score 6):

The spell doesn't limit you to moving it only within range of where you were standing when you cast it, because range is always measured from you when no other way to measure a range is stated, and *major image* says only “within range” without modification:

> As long as you are within range of the illusion, you can use your action to cause the image to move to any other spot within range.

So that last “within range” necessarily means within range of *you*.

So **yes**, after it is cast, you can move it anywhere within range of *you*, regardless of what the original "range sphere" might have been, because the spell doesn't anywhere suggest a way or thing to measure range from other than yourself. This means that [you can take it with you cross-country, so long as the duration and your actions permit](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84383/without-home-brew-are-there-ways-of-carrying-illusions).