# Action surge phb vs br

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, fighter

The Basic Rules state that you can get a possible bonus action. Is this entirely up to the dm or are there circumstances where it is guaranteed?
Players handbook doesn't include the bonus action.

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate as it's not a question of Action Surge giving a second Bonus Action, but that the rules are stated differently between SRD and PHB and so you may lose out on a Bonus Action.

Comment: @Miva It's not clear to me where the reference to the SRD PDF is coming from. Did you figure out what rule the OP is referring to and then research the wording between the two sources yourself? The real confusion in my eyes is that the title mentions Action Surge but the body of the question is asking about bonus actions (without reference to Action Surge).

Comment: Relevant question: "[As of the November 2018 core book updates, what changes were made in the latest printings of the PHB that aren't noted in the errata document?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/168348)", one such change is to the wording of Action Surge.

Comment: @Rykara, I read the question. It stated there was a difference between the Basic Rules and the PHB. So I looked up the wording of Action Surge for both, and yes, there is a difference. That's why I put links to both in my answer.

Comment: @MivaScott: The description of Action Surge in the combined basic rules PDF as of the 2018 update does not differ from the one in the PHB. (The SRD, which hasn't been updated since 2016, is indeed out of date, but the SRD and the basic rules aren't the same thing.) Thus, if OP clarifies where they saw such a distinction, we can help clear things up.

Comment: Also: Werdna, welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The PHB is only talking about getting an additional Action on top of your normal Action and "possible" bonus action.

On your turn you always have access to your Bonus Action. Its just that things that require a bonus action are not that prevalent, so you don't always use it.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. Also, neither the PHB nor the basic rules currently reference a "possible" bonus action; that was removed as of the 2018 core rules updates/errata, though [that particular change is not mentioned in the errata PDF](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/150613/as-of-the-november-2018-core-book-updates-what-changes-were-made-in-the-latest).